# Fill a table or list of values in textarea in website using Splinter

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, splinter

I am trying to write a script to automate the search for multiple entries. Here is the input:

```
<mirna-1>
<mirna-2>
<mirna-3>
    :    
    :
```

The website address is `https://www.mirnet.ca/miRNet/faces/upload/MirUploadView.xhtml`

[image]

How can I fill mirna-1,.... into miRNA list box. I have made the following attempts but failed:

```py
gecko = os.path.normpath('~/geckodriver')
nirnet_Results = []`
browser = Browser(executable_path=gecko)
browser.visit('https://www.mirnet.ca/miRNet/faces/home.xhtml')

# click miRNA_list
xpath = '//*[@id="j_idt39:j_idt55"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)

#Select Human
xpath = '//*[@id="form:j_idt34"]/div[3]/span'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)
xpath = '//*[@id="form:j_idt34_1"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)

# select miRBase ID type
xpath = '//*[@id="form:j_idt38"]/div[3]/span'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)
xpath = '//*[@id="form:j_idt38_1"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)

# select Tissue type
xpath = '//*[@id="form:sourceOpt"]/div[3]/span'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)
xpath = '//*[@id="form:sourceOpt_1"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)

# select target type
xpath = '//*[@id="form:targetOpts"]/div[3]/span'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)
xpath = '//*[@id="form:targetOpts_1"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)

# Fill miRNA list
xpath = '//*[@id="form:listData"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
time.sleep(1)
for mir in known_mir:
    browser.fill('form:listData',mir)
    browser.fill('form:listData','\n')
```

I am getting success in selecting options in starting drop-down list and when I try to paste a list of names in the miRNA list, I am getting all the names like this:

`<mirna-1><mirna-2><mirna-3>....`

while the right format is each name should in the next line. How to do this. Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would recommend selenium for something like this, it seems you want to stick with splinter. The following fix using splinter. When reproducing this issue, each time `browser.fill()` is run it replaces the text already written. Since you didn't include what `known_mir` was in your code, I am assuming it is a list (correct me if I'm wrong). I tried combining what you wanted to put into the form and it worked.

Replace:

```py
for mir in known_mir:

    browser.fill('form:listData',mir)

    browser.fill('form:listData','\n')
```

With:

```py
browser.fill('form:listData', '\n'.join(mir for mir in known_mir))
```

All my code does is combine each of the strings in `known_mir`.

Comment: Thanks for reply after so many days. But unfortunately I can't accept it as correct answer because it is incomplete as I have mentioned in reputation box.  I started this task with splinter. So if you recommend selenium, I request you complete your answer for other task also e.g. 1. select miRNA list, 2. select human, 3. select mirbase ID and so on and proceed [two times continuously] and finally save network image in SVG format in selenium only. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lot_to_learn Sorry if my answer was unclear. Although I recommend this task with selenium, the answer I provided is using splinter. My answer just corrects the code that fills the mIRNA List.

Answer (score 2):

You can fill this form Using `Selenium Chrome Driver` and `python`.If you haven't use selenium before and would like use selenium.However here is the [official website](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) of selenium.

---

To `install` selenium use command line

> pip install -U selenium

---

You need download chrome driver from following website [website Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) based on `compatibility`,such as which `chrome browser` supports by the `chrome driver`.Always prefer the latest versions of chrome driver and chrome browser.

---

Here is the selenium code which fills the form

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome('path to chrome driver exe')  #example : 'C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
driver.get("https://www.mirnet.ca/miRNet/faces/upload/MirUploadView.xhtml")

#select Organism here
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"form:j_idt34_label"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']//ul[@id='form:j_idt34_items']//li[contains(.,'H. sapiens (human)')]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.UP).send_keys(Keys.DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

#select ID type here
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"form:j_idt38_label"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']//ul[@id='form:j_idt38_items']//li[contains(.,'miRBase ID')]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.UP).send_keys(Keys.DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

#select Tissue here
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"form:sourceOpt_label"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']//ul[@id='form:sourceOpt_items']//li[contains(.,'Exosomes [1250]')]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.UP).send_keys(Keys.DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

#select Target type here

WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"form:targetOpts_label"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']//ul[@id='form:targetOpts_items']//li[contains(.,'Genes')]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.UP).send_keys(Keys.DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()


items=['mirna-1','mirna-2','mirna-3','mirna-4']
for item in items:
   element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//textarea[@id='form:listData']")))
   element.send_keys(item)
   element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although your answer is very correct and you tried to give complete solution. I really appreciate your efforts. The above user (@Lucky..) has already given answer. I commented without checking it. Not its working and he is the first one to answer so he deserves. You also deserves equally but I can't give +50 to 2 guys [sorry for that]. Thanks for your help. Problem solved.

Comment: @Lot_to_learn : I know you can't accept two answers but you can up vote the answer so that future reader can use it if they required.